# How to enable default retry mechanism in Azkaban

Tags: python, azkaban

There is a way we can specify the retry in job as below

```
from azkaban import Job, Project
project = Project('azkaban_basic_flow', root=__file__)
project.properties['retries'] = '3' #line 3
project.properties['retry.backoff'] = '60000' #line 4
```

Say we have 10 projects - We need to hard code the lines 3 and 4 in all 10 projects. Is there any way we can enable the default retry mechanism, So that it can be inherited to all projects by default.

Answer (score 1):

Global level properties should be defined in common.properties and that can be consumed through out the azkaban projects.(**azkaban-version:3.1.0**)

### ***Steps to follow:***

1. Navigate to *azkaban-exec-server-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/plugins/jobtypes/* and create common.properties
2. Place the content inside common.properties `retries=3 
   retry.backoff=30000`
3. Use the property defined in common.properties inside  azkaban-exec-server-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/plugins/jobtypes/jobtype-name/plugin.properties.
4. restart azkaban-executor to reflect the changes.
5. Now the property can be access inside azkaban project using `${retries}` and `${retry.backoff}`

Reference documentation: [azkaban documentation](http://azkaban.github.io/azkaban/docs/latest/)